# Como obter a coordenada X se a condição de Y for cumprida com o Numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

Eu criei uma função que me dá esta matriz como output em que cada **linha corresponde a um ponto**  :

```
array([[0.57946528, 2.        ],
      [0.35226154, 0.        ],
      [0.26088698, 0.        ],
      [0.56560726, 1.        ],
      [0.41680759, 1.        ],
      [0.55771505, 0.        ],
      [0.8501109 , 0.        ],
      [0.76229916, 1.        ],
      [0.50357436, 0.        ],
      [0.40875861, 1.        ]])
```

Eu pretendo agrupar os pontos pelo valor único da coordenada Y (np.unique(y)) e calcular a sua média por valor de Y (x_media para y = 0, x_media para y = 1,x_media para y = 2).

Desta forma, o novo array só teria três pontos(3 linhas e duas colunas)

```
array([[mean(x, y =2) , 2.        ],
      [mean(x, y = 0) / , 0.        ],
      [mean(x, y= 1),0.        ]])
```

Já pensei em transformar este array num dataframe com pandas mas ando à procura de fazer isto com o numpy

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nessa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38015063/664577). O pacote [numpy-indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) parece fazer exatamente o que você quer: `npi.group_by(a[:, 0]).mean(a[:, 1])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os valores:

```
a =  np.array([
      [0.57946528, 2.        ],
      [0.35226154, 0.        ],
      [0.26088698, 0.        ],
      [0.56560726, 1.        ],
      [0.41680759, 1.        ],
      [0.55771505, 0.        ],
      [0.8501109 , 0.        ],
      [0.76229916, 1.        ],
      [0.50357436, 0.        ],
      [0.40875861, 1.        ]])
```

Uma alternativa com numpy:

```
import numpy as np

X = a[:,0] # valores de X
Y = a[:,1] # valores de Y
Y_unic = np.unique(Y) # valores únicos de Y

b = [([X[Y == y], y]) for y in Y_unic] # criando uma lista de array numpy com os valores agrupados
np.array([[np.mean(y), x] for y, x in b]) # calculando a média
```

Saída:

```
array([[0.50490977, 0.        ],
       [0.53836816, 1.        ],
       [0.57946528, 2.        ]])
```

Com pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'X':a[:,0], 'Y':a[:,1]})
df = df.groupby('Y').mean().reset_index().reindex(columns=['X','Y']).values
df
```

Saída:

```
array([[0.50490977, 0.        ],
       [0.53836816, 1.        ],
       [0.57946528, 2.        ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que não tenha um método numpy para fazer isso. Certamente com o pandas seria mais fácil.

Mas, uma vez que vc quer fazer com numpy, acredito que o caminho seja:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> arr = np.array([[0.57946528, 2.        ],
...       [0.35226154, 0.        ],
...       [0.26088698, 0.        ],
...       [0.56560726, 1.        ],
...       [0.41680759, 1.        ],
...       [0.55771505, 0.        ],
...       [0.8501109 , 0.        ],
...       [0.76229916, 1.        ],
...       [0.50357436, 0.        ],
...       [0.40875861, 1.        ]])

>>> n = np.unique(arr[:,1])

>>> n
array([0., 1., 2.])

>>> ga = np.array( [ [i, list(arr[arr[:,1]==i,0])] for i in n], dtype=object )
>>> ga
array([[0.0,
        list([0.35226154, 0.26088698, 0.55771505, 0.8501109, 0.50357436])],
       [1.0, list([0.56560726, 0.41680759, 0.76229916, 0.40875861])],
       [2.0, list([0.57946528])]], dtype=object)

>>> final = np.array( [[i, np.mean(j) ] for i, j in ga] )
>>> final
array([[0.        , 0.50490977],
       [1.        , 0.53836816],
       [2.        , 0.57946528]])
>>>
```

Espero que ajude.